# Format and rewrite xml file

Tags: c#, xml

I have this xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><test1 name="all">
  <section name="Header"><holder name="top" >top</holder><holder name="banner">banner</holder></section>
  </test1>
```

I want to  format this file in a manage way like this(at least line break):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<test1 name="all">
<section name="Header">
<holder name="top" >top</holder>
<holder name="banner">banner</holder>
</section>
</test1>
```

in c#

```
   XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Load("file.xml"); //load file 
    foreach(xml node ...) //Need help for this logic 
    {
     //...Add line break ....
    }
```

Comment: You can reformat the file as you load it from file.xml; any specific reason why that is not an option ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get file with formatted XML, then you just save `xmlDoc`.

```
XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Load("file.xml"); //load file    
xmlDoc.Save("formatted.file.xml");
```

But it will be fully formatted (with indentations).